# How to break datetime in 12 hour chunks and use it for aggregation in Presto SQL?

Tags: sql, presto

I have been trying to break the datetime in 12 hour chunk in Presto SQL but was unsuccessful.

Raw data table:

| datetime | Login |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-05-08 07:10:00.000 | 1234 |
| 2022-05-09 23:20:00.000 | 5678 |
| 2022-05-09 06:20:00.000 | 5674 |
| 2022-05-08 09:20:00.000 | 8971 |

The output table should look like below. I have to get count of login in 12 hour chunks. So, first should be from 00:00:00.000 to 11:59:00:000 and the next chunk from 12:00:00.000 to 23:59:00:000

Output:

| datetime | count |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-05-08 00:00:00.000 | 2 |
| 2022-05-08 12:00:00.000 | 0 |
| 2022-05-09 00:00:00.000 | 1 |
| 2022-05-09 12:20:00.000 | 1 |

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

Extract the hour from the timestamp, then integer divide it by 12. That will make it 0 till 11:59, and 1 till 23:59. Then, multiply that back by 12.

Use that resulting integer to `DATE_ADD()` it with unit 'HOUR' to the timestamp of the row truncated to the day.

```
SELECT                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  DATE_ADD('HOUR',(HOUR(ts) / 12) * 12, TRUNC(ts,'DAY')) AS halfday
, SUM(login) AS count_login
FROM indata
GROUP BY
  halfday
;
-- out        halfday       | count_login 
-- out ---------------------+-------------
-- out  2022-05-08 00:00:00 |       15879
-- out  2022-05-08 12:00:00 |        5678
```

Comment: Thanks! Trunc function didn't work in presto. I used date_trunc instead.

Answer (score 0):

This query worked for me.

```
SELECT                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  DATE_ADD('HOUR',(HOUR(ts) / 12) * 12, date_trunc('DAY',ts)) AS halfday
, SUM(login) AS count_login
FROM indata
GROUP BY
  halfday
;
```